# String contains a lot of copies, how to get rid of them?

Tags: c#, .net, string, copy

I got something like this:

```
string s="Solid;Solid;Gass;Solid;Solid;Gass;Solid;Gass;Liquid;Liquid;"
```

and now I want to get rid of the copies in the string...so that in the end `s` should be like this:

```
s="Solid;Gass;Liquid;"
```

Comment: Split string, distinct, join. Try searching.

Comment: Is here also a duplicate: `Soli;Solid`? So do you want to compare only complete tokens/words or also substrings?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't for homework questions.

Comment: @Robin - Yes it is, it is for all questions, providing they follow the guidelines such as showing research/effort. Although this question does not. Stefan, please read [ask]

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var parts = s.Split(';');
var distinctParts = parts.Distinct();
var newString = string.Join(";", distinctParts);
```

Where:

- [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will give you an array with all the words of your string, taking the specified character as the word separator (`;` in this case).
- [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will give your a collection with the unique words of your array.
- Finally, [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) composes a new string with the unique words, using the specified string (`;`in this case) as the separator.

Comment: Don't dump code. Explain what this does.

Comment: To be fair this is more explanatory just because of the variable naming... granted not extremely explicit

Comment: Honestly, I don't think that such a small piece of code, using such explicitly named library methods, and using properly named variables, needs too much explanation. IMHO.

Comment: You're right in that it is very clear what methods you call and what your variables contain, but still "try this" is not a proper explanation. You can still explain the concept behind what this code does.

Comment: Ok, done. Can I get my two rep points back? ;-P

Answer (score 3):

You can split the string, then find the distinct instances and join them back in one line:

```
string s = "Solid;Solid;Gass;Solid;Solid;Gass;Solid;Gass;Liquid;Liquid;";
s = string.Join(";", s.Split(';').Distinct());
```

Comment: Don't dump code. Explain what this does.

Comment: @CodeCaster, to be fair the first poster normally gets the upvotes, so "post fast, elaborate later" is effectively encouraged by the system. Giving people a few minutes to elaborate before asking is appropriate IMO.